# Как убрать рамку в низу блока

Tags: css3, css

Есть блок `header` внизу этого блока меню. Задача состоит в том, чтобы убрать рамку внизу блока где меню, а там где меню кончаеться рамка должна оставаться.

Для примера обратите внимание на нижнее меню справа (старые новые ценные) на против того где указано сколько ответов  получено на вопрос

Вот часть кода css:

```
#header

{

    background:#DCDCDC;

    height:157px;

    border-bottom:grey 1px inset;

}

#menu1

{

    position:relative;

    top:1px;

}

#menu1 ul

{

    list-style:none;

}

#menu1 li

{

    list-style:none;

    display:block;

    float:left;

    background:#DCDCDC;

    height:30px;

    line-height:30px;

    border-width:0 2px 0 2px;

    padding:0px 5px 0 5px;

}

#menu1 li a

{

    color:grey;

}

#menu1 li:hover

{

    border-top:inset 1px #DCDCDC;

    border-left:inset 1px #DCDCDC;

    border-right:inset 1px #DCDCDC;

    background:white;

}

#menu1 li.carent

{

    border-top:inset 1px #DCDCDC;

    border-left:inset 1px #DCDCDC;

    border-right:inset 1px #DCDCDC;

    background:white;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду, что все элементы foo кроме последнего должны быть без нижней границы, то так:

```
.foo {border-bottom: 0}
.foo:last-child {border-bottom: 1px}
```

Если вы имеете в виду, что все элементы foo внутри блока bar должны быть без границы, а вне блока bar - с границей, то так:

```
.foo {border-bottom: 1px}
#bar .foo {border-bottom: 0}
```